# How to determine the sum of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^k}{(k!)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^k}{(k!)^2}$$

The series converges by the ratio test but how would I find out the exact sum of the series.

Comment: no reason to think there is a nice closed-form expression for the sum. Why do you ask?

Comment: Well, its on an old test from one of my classes, and the sum was asked for. I'm correct in saying it converges, at least?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606426/series-sum-n-1-infty-fracnnn2)

Answer (score 1):

The sum seems to converge, since $k^k \approx \frac{k!e^k}{\sqrt{2 \pi k}}$ using Stirling's approximation. Cancelling out $k!$ the summand becomes 
$
\frac{e^k}{k!\sqrt{2 \pi k}} < \frac{e^k}{k!} 
$ 
for $k \geq 1$. since the latter sum clearly converges to $e^{e}-1$, by comparison test the former sum converges too.

EDIT: it does seem to have a numerical solution too:

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k^k%2F%28%28k!%29^2%29%2Ck%3D1..ifinity%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%5Ek/%28%28k!%29%5E2%29,k=1..ifinity%29)

Comment: Not really answering the question, the OP already knows it converges...

Comment: @L.F.: in the discussion above the OP asks if the sum is convergent