# Series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to study the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}$$
All the terms are positive.
But I can't solve the limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^n}{(n!)^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n^2}*\frac{n}{(n-1)^2}*\frac{n}{(n-2)^2}*...*\frac{n}{9}*\frac{n}{4}*n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{(n-1)^2}*\frac{n}{(n-2)^2}*...*\frac{n}{9}*\frac{n}{4}$$

the first term of the product tends to $\frac{1}{n}$ but I can't say that all the product is $<\frac{1}{n}$ because the other terms 
are $>\frac{1}{n}$

how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you asking *does this series converge* or *what is its value*?

Comment: Checking just convergence is a routine application of the Stirling approximation (which basically says $n^n/n! \sim e^n$).

Comment: One doesn't "solve" a limit, one "evaluates" a limit.

Comment: Try to exploit the elementary inequality $n!\geq \frac{n^n}{e^n}$ in order to deduce that the given series is convergent by comparison with a geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cauchy root test and Stirling's approximation for factorial ($n!\approx (\frac{n}{e})^n$) we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{n^n}{(n!)^2})^{\frac{1}{n}}=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{(\frac{n}{e})^2}=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^2}{n}=0$$
which implies on convergence but I don't think the value of it to be calculated at all!

Comment: the argument of the limit is not elevated to 1/n

Comment: @Anne Mostafa used the root test. What you were doing would have only told you the terms are going to zero, which isn't enough to determine whether the series converges.

Comment: @Ian Now I understand what Mostafa did. But I can't understand why $n!=n/e$...I would have used the asindotic test. Anyway I don't understand why the limit is 0

Comment: @Anne Mostafa used the Stirling approximation to the factorial. One way to prove this is to write $n!=e^{\log(n!)}=e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k)}=e^{n\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n \log(k/n)} \approx e^{n \log(n)+n\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx}=e^{n\log(n)-n}$.

Comment: @Ian thank you for your explanation, now it all clear about Mostafa's solution...but applying the same approximation to the limit it comes $\frac{e^{2n}}{n^n}$...

Comment: @Anne The limit without the $1/n$ exponent can only tell you that the series diverges, it can't tell you that it converges even if it does. Using the $1/n$ exponent as Mostafa did is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 4):

Without sophisticated tools like Stirling's formula, the *ratio test* works fine here:
$$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{\bigl((n+1)!\bigr)^2}\cdot\frac{(n!)^2}{n^n}=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2}\biggl(\frac{n+1}n\biggr)^n=\frac1{n+1}\biggl(\frac{n+1}n\biggr)^n $$
which tends to $0$ since the second factor tends to $\mathrm e$.