# Does this series converges? Ratio Test, Factorial Numerator and exponential Denominator

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A k!}{B k^k}$ where $A, \, B > 0$
Does this series converges?
If A is different than B, then it obviously converges with the ratio test.
But with $ A = B $. How would I know it converges?
So being more precise, does $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{k^k}$ converges? ( Because in this way, the ratio test gives $1^-$, which is inconclusive )

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are constants; move them out of the sum so it doesn't matter if $A = B$.  (... or did you mean $\dots / (Bk)^k$ or something other than what you wrote?)

Comment: You should be able to adapt [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2606582/123905) to determine the limit of the summands (just to see if they go to zero before trying anything fancy)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A, B > 0$ then the sum converges. Namely, it's a serie defintely non-negative. Let:
$$a_n=\frac{A}{B}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}$$
We can use the root citeria. We have:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{A}{B}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{A}{B}}\cdot\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$

[In my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4310857/686644), I've showned that:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\frac{1}{e}$$

So:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{A}{B}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{A}{B}}\cdot\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=0^+$$

Thus, the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the sum converges. It can be proved using the direct comparison test.

We can prove that for $k>5$, $$\frac1{k^2} > \frac{k!}{k^k}$$ and since the sum over $1/k^2$ converges, the same can be said for $k!/k^k$.

Hope that's convincing.

Comment: It would help if you can elaborate on how one would go about proving the inequality, as it may not be exactly trivial to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the ratio test do some calculations and use $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ tends to $\exp(x)$ as $n$ tends to infinity. This would give you convergence